# Hyperlink within .py to .docx (nominally Sphinx)

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docx, cross-reference

**Context:**
I have requirements documents in .docx form, and I've made immutable bookmark tags and established hyperlinks through them, so can trace from user requirements through to software requirements.

I would like to tag within the source code (.py) where I have implemented the solutions to requirements so an auto-generated design doc is also part of the traceable system.

**Problem:**
To that end, have tried various things within sphinx.
Given a hyperlink within a word docx, say:

```
//example.com/DriveName/example.docx#SRS_20230329_131000
```

Trying to tag to it via:

```
:ref:
```

and

```
:doc:
```

also tried

```
:download:
```

Within a .py docstring then building an SDD via sphinx is just giving me a block of text, i.e.

```
:ref:’SRS-0020<//example.com/DriveName/example.docx#SRS_20230329_131000>’_
```

I'm hoping intersphinx does it, and I am just not doing it right. Anyone any suggestions?

(Alternative doc-generators that would do it would be considered)

edit: Example doc-string below

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
"""
**Instantiate the class**

:param kwargs: Optional dictionary of keyword-val arguments
:type kwargs: dictionary
:param script_in: Full path to the script to load
:type script_in: string                
:param message_handler: Handle to message_handler
:type message_hander: <handle>
   
:return: [None]
    
Requirements
------------
:ref:’SRS-0020<file:////example.com/DriveName/example.docx#SRS_20230329_131000>’__

"""
```

Have put in file:// preceeding the network path per Mikko's suggestion below

Comment: Yep, so the docstring within the .py file would contain a cross-reference [will make an addin for spyder later to help developer insert them]. So later on, can trace from high level right down to code implementation.

Comment: Sorry, 5 mins elapsed - and the sphinx generated SDD would show the requirement item (with the "immutable" hyperlink tag hidden underneath)

Comment: Spyder = IDE. As the raw hyperlink is a bit clumbersome to work with, the IDE would eventually present the developer with a list of requirements (identified by the "SRS-0020") which they'd then insert into the .py - and that insertion process would automatically add the hyperlink. None of which is core to this problem - just pre-empting questions of how unwieldy the hyperlink appears.

Comment: `:doc:` and `:ref:` are used when the link target is a .rst document or a specific label in a .rst document. You can't use these roles to link to .docx files.

Comment: Thanks mzjn - I kinda suspected as much, but good to have it confirmed - I tried :download: as well, but no joy. (Will add that to main question)

Comment: `:download:` is for non-RST files *within your source tree* (not remote files).

Comment: Ah, didn't realise that thanks mzjn. Take it you don't know of an invocation for a remote file?

Comment: Nope - unfortunately not. Comment in to that effect (30 Mar 08:06)

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx can use hyperlinks and hyperlinks can be any URIs.

[Learn what is `file://` URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Something like this should work:

```
`SRS-0020 <file:////example.com/DriveName/example.docx#SRS_20230329_131000>`__
```

However the actual scheme depends on your file system layout, might be affected Windows version and such so you need to first study how to create `file://` URLs in normal HTML.

`file://` URLs might be disabled by web browser due to security reasons.

Comment: Hmm, I had already tried it with file://example.com (etc) - with no joy. I would have expected that to manifiest as a dud hyperlink, but still ended up with the raw text. Just tried it using :download: and didn't work. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: First you need to learn how to make links in HTML. Then transfer this knowledge to Sphinx. It's a different question overall how to make file:// links in Windows.

Comment: Ha - admittedly while I had completely forgotten the reforming of html links (%20 etc) - that hasn't changed the presentation in the sphinx produced .html, using either :download: or :ref: